# How to create a quantum circuit transforming $α|00⟩ + β|11⟩$ to $β|00⟩-α|01⟩+β|10⟩+α|11⟩$

Tags: circuit-construction, textbook-and-exercises

Starting from an unknown state $α|00⟩ + β|11⟩$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are properly normalized, *how can I create a circuit that transforms that state to a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (β|00⟩-α|01⟩+β|10⟩+α|11⟩)$ state?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the output state can be written as,

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\beta|00\rangle - \alpha|01\rangle + \beta|10\rangle + \alpha|11\rangle)$

= $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\beta(|00\rangle + |10\rangle) - \alpha(|01\rangle - |11\rangle))$

= $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\beta(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)|0\rangle - \alpha(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)|1\rangle)$

= $\beta|+\rangle|0\rangle - \alpha|-\rangle|1\rangle$

= $\beta(H|0\rangle)|0\rangle - \alpha(H|1\rangle)|1\rangle$

Where $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ are the two orthogonal x-basis states:
$$|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle) = H|0\rangle$$
$$|-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle) = H|1\rangle$$​
And $H$ is the Hadamard gate.

To create the circuit first note that in the final state $\alpha$ is amplitude of the state $|11\rangle$ instead of $|00\rangle$. The opposite happens with $\beta$. It is a *bit-flip* operation. So, we need to apply $X$-gate to both qubits. The resulting state will be
$$\beta|00\rangle + \alpha|11\rangle$$
Then we need to change the sign of the $|11\rangle$ state. It is a *phase-flip* operation. So, we need to apply $Z$-gate to any one of the qubits. Now we have,
$$\beta|00\rangle - \alpha|11\rangle$$
Finally, we need to apply $H$-gate to the second qubit.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Egretta-Thula for the answer. I don't understand what happened on line 4 of the answer.

Comment: [@Hamideh](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/19052/hamideh), it is just a simple replacement. I updated my answer to be more clear. If you need any further clarification please let me know.

Comment: I don't know about the circuit yet. It seems to me that I need an H, a swap and a z gate? Can you please help me with inferring the gates?

Comment: Now my answer contains the circuit.

Comment: Thanks. Why did you add the H gate to the second qubit?

Comment: I assumed **little-endian notation** which means that if the state is $|01\rangle$ then the first qubit is $|1\rangle$ and the second qubit is $|0\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

Since the circuit `U` is linear (as always) you can investigate its action to each input independently:

$$
\begin{align}
U\bigl(\alpha|00\rangle + \beta|11\rangle\bigr) &= \alpha U|00\rangle + \beta U|11\rangle\\
&=\alpha\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(-|01\rangle +|11\rangle\bigr) + \beta\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(|00\rangle + |10\rangle\bigr)
\end{align}
$$

You, therefore, need a circuit that acts as:

$$
\begin{align}
U|00\rangle &= \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(-|01\rangle + |11\rangle\bigr) \\
U|11\rangle &= \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(|00\rangle + |10\rangle\bigr)
\end{align}
$$

It is obvious that there is no *one* unique circuit that achieves this since you don't know its action on $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$.

Next you can check if the right hand side contains entangled qubits or not so that you know if you need entangling (two-qubit) gates or not. Obviously, they are not entangled:

$$
\begin{align}
-|01\rangle +|11\rangle &= -\bigr(|0\rangle -|1\rangle\bigl)|1\rangle = -\bigr(H|1\rangle\bigl)|1\rangle\\
|00\rangle +|10\rangle &= \bigr(|0\rangle +|1\rangle\bigl)|0\rangle = \bigr(H|0\rangle\bigl)|0\rangle\\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, the action of $U$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
U|00\rangle &= \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(-|01\rangle + |11\rangle\bigr) \\
&= -HI|11\rangle \\
&= HZ|11\rangle \\
&= (HZ)(XX)|00\rangle
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
U|11\rangle &= \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(|00\rangle + |10\rangle\bigr) \\
&= HI|00\rangle\\
&= (HI)(XX)|11\rangle \\
&= (HZ)(XX)|11\rangle
\end{align}
$$

where in the last step we replaced $I$ with $Z$ since it has no effect on the state $|00\rangle$.

So one possible circuit that transforms your input state to the desired output state is a circuit with two $X$ gates followed by a $H$ gate on one qubit and a $Z$ gate on the other.